# Refactoring a React PureComponent to a hooks based functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, components, react-hooks

I have a working [class based implementation of an Accordion component](https://codesandbox.io/s/4pyqoxoz9?fontsize=14) which I'm [trying to refactor](https://codesandbox.io/s/lxp8xz80z7) to use the new [hooks api](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html).

My main challenge is to find a way to re-render only the toggled `<AccordionSection />` while preventing all the other `<AccordionSection/>` components from re-rendering every time the state of the parent `<Accordion/>` (which keeps track of the open sections on its state) is updated.

On the class-based implementation I've managed to achieve this by making the `<AccordionSection />` a `PureComponent`, passing the `isOpen` and `onClick` callbacks to it via a higher-order component which utilizes the `context` API, **and** by saving these callbacks on the parent `<Accordion/>`'s component's state as follows:

```
this.state = {
      /.../
      onClick: this.onClick,
      isOpen: this.isOpen
    };
```

which, to my understanding, keeps the reference to them and thus prevents them from being created as new instances on each `<Accordion />` update.

However, I can't seem to get this to work with the hooks-based implementation.

Some of the things I've already tried to no success:

1. Wrapping the Accordion section with `memo` - including various render conditions on the second callback argument.
2. wrapping the `onClick` and `isOpen` callbacks with `useCallback` (doesn't seem to work since they have dependencies which update on each `<Accordion/>` render)
3. saving the `onClick` and `isOpen` to the state like this: `const [callbacks] = useState({onClick, isOpen})` and then passing the `callbacks` object as the `ContextProvider` `value`. (seems wrong, and didn't work)

Here are the references to my working class-based implementation:

https://codesandbox.io/s/4pyqoxoz9

and my hooks refactor attempt:

https://codesandbox.io/s/lxp8xz80z7

I kept the logs on the `<AccordionSection/>` render in order to demonstrate which re-renders I'm trying to prevent.

Any inputs will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

so I ended up adding this little nugget after chasing too many rabbits..

```
const cache = {};

const AccordionSection = memo(({ children, sectionSlug, onClick, isOpen }) => {
  if (cache[sectionSlug]) {
    console.log({
      children: children === cache[sectionSlug].children,
      sectionSlug: sectionSlug === cache[sectionSlug].sectionSlug,
      onClick: onClick === cache[sectionSlug].onClick,
      isOpen: isOpen === cache[sectionSlug].isOpen
    });
  }
  cache[sectionSlug] = { children, sectionSlug, onClick, isOpen };
```

This showed that it was `onClick` that was changing. Which then seems obvious as the Accordion component is rendering and creating a new `onClick`.

wrapping he `onClick` creation with `useCallback` rectifies the issue.

```
const onClick = useCallback(
  sectionSlug =>
    setOpenSections({
      ...(exclusive ? {} : openSections),
      [sectionSlug]: !openSections[sectionSlug]
    }),
  []
);
```

though I do seem to have broken `exclusive` in the process as it's always enabled now..

https://codesandbox.io/s/1o08p08m27

oh, I did move a few other pieces around in there that might have contributed to the fix..

**Update**

refactored to use `useReducer` and moved all the logic there so we can deliver a stable `onClick`

**Update**

they say sleep is good, but for me it's just trying to get to sleep..

I knew there was something I was missing.. realised last night we don't need the reducer, just the function form of `setState` which allows us to access the up-to-date state from within the `useCallback` memoed function. Converted @itaydafna's optimisation here https://codesandbox.io/s/8490v55029

Comment: thanks @lecstor for your time. However, this doesn't solve the issue. I think the reason the Accordion is now always `exclusive` is that wrapping the `onClick` with a `useCallback` without passing anything into the (mandatory) dependancy array prevents the value of `openSections` in the callback from changing so it just resolves to the initial `openSections` provided to `useState` (an empty object). this can be fixed if you pass `[openSections]` into the dependancy array like this: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/ox9z3x8ry9
however - now we'er back to the initial multi section render issue :(

Comment: mm, yeh. it's easy if you make the accordion a class component.. OR, you can `useReducer` 8) I think it's working now..

Comment: great solution! By using `useReducer` (and `dispatch` in the `onClick`) you canceled `onClick`'s dependency on `openSections` which actually makes the `useCallback` wrapping it effective. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: and here is another small optimisation to your solution with a simpler reducer which tracks only the openSections state ('exclusive' doesn't actually have to be kept on the state):

https://codesandbox.io/s/1vq390no0j

Comment: sweet! and trying to get to sleep last night I realised what I was missing all along.. the function form of `setState`.. no reducer required.. https://codesandbox.io/s/8490v55029